# Removing Icon from a WPF window

Tags: wpf, user-interface

I am able to remove the window icon from WPF window using WinApi's, however I get the icon again in the application window when I run just the executable of the WPF project.

How do I remove the icon?

Comment: What is the difference between a WPF window and the application window.
And please accept answers to previous questions if you want answers to new questions.

Comment: Yep, please accept answers to previous questions first.

Comment: @LdnCobra, excellent answer, but you did not give shraddha an incentive to accept answers to old questions :-)

Comment: ya i dont knw how to accept...i m not able to find direct link to accpting ans...rather i culdnt see previous ans...

Comment: just click the tick box on the answer that has helped you.

Comment: @shraddha : use the "tick" icon next to the answer you want to accept. http://sstatic.net/so/img/vote-accepted.png

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have modified the sample from 'LnDCobra' so it can be used as an attached property (as 'Thomas' suggested:

```
<Window 
        ...
        xmlns:i="clr-namespace:namespace-to-WindowEx"
        i:WindowEx.ShowIcon = "false"
        ...
>
```

Implementation of WindowEx:

```
public class WindowEx
  {
    private const int GwlExstyle = -20;
    private const int SwpFramechanged = 0x0020;
    private const int SwpNomove = 0x0002;
    private const int SwpNosize = 0x0001;
    private const int SwpNozorder = 0x0004;
    private const int WsExDlgmodalframe = 0x0001;

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ShowIconProperty =
      DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "ShowIcon",
        typeof (bool),
        typeof (WindowEx),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(true, new PropertyChangedCallback((d, e) => RemoveIcon((Window) d))));


    public static Boolean GetShowIcon(UIElement element)
    {
      return (Boolean) element.GetValue(ShowIconProperty);
    }

    public static void RemoveIcon(Window window)
    {
      window.SourceInitialized += delegate {
        // Get this window's handle
        var hwnd = new WindowInteropHelper(window).Handle;

        // Change the extended window style to not show a window icon
        int extendedStyle = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GwlExstyle);
        SetWindowLong(hwnd, GwlExstyle, extendedStyle | WsExDlgmodalframe);

        // Update the window's non-client area to reflect the changes
        SetWindowPos(hwnd, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, 0, 0, SwpNomove |
          SwpNosize | SwpNozorder | SwpFramechanged);
      };
    }

    public static void SetShowIcon(UIElement element, Boolean value)
    {
      element.SetValue(ShowIconProperty, value);
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hwnd, int index);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, uint msg,
      IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hwnd, int index, int newStyle);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr hwndInsertAfter,
      int x, int y, int width, int height, uint flags);
  }
}
```

Comment: For me this works fine in debug mode but not if I run it outside the debug environment.

Comment: the accepted answer didn't work in .NET4.5 while your answer worked for me. thanks! 
worked both from visual studio in debug mode as well as by running the exe from windows explorer.

Comment: This answer worked for me in .NET4.5 when I combined it with this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18580430/hide-the-icon-from-a-wpf-window. Also XAML designer complained that it cannot cast WindowsInstance to Window, so I had to rewrite it a bit and remove direct cast to window: `PropertyChangedCallback((d, e) => RemoveIcon((Window) d)`;

Answer (score 27):

From [WPFTutorial](http://www.wpftutorial.net/RemoveIcon.html):

How to remove the icon of a WPF window

[image]

Unfortunately WPF does not provide any function to remove the icon of a window. One solution could be setting the icon to a transparent icon. But this way the extra space between the window border and title remains.

The better approach is to use a function provided by the Win32 API to remove the icon.

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
    {
        IconHelper.RemoveIcon(this);
    }
}
```

A helper class used to remove the icon.

```
public static class IconHelper
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hwnd, int index);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hwnd, int index, int newStyle);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr hwndInsertAfter, 
        int x, int y, int width, int height, uint flags);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, uint msg, 
        IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    const int GWL_EXSTYLE = -20;
    const int WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAME = 0x0001;
    const int SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
    const int SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;
    const int SWP_NOZORDER = 0x0004;
    const int SWP_FRAMECHANGED = 0x0020;
    const uint WM_SETICON = 0x0080;

    public static void RemoveIcon(Window window)
    {
        // Get this window's handle
        IntPtr hwnd = new WindowInteropHelper(window).Handle;

        // Change the extended window style to not show a window icon
        int extendedStyle = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);
        SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, extendedStyle | WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAME);

        // Update the window's non-client area to reflect the changes
        SetWindowPos(hwnd, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | 
              SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_FRAMECHANGED);
    }
}
```

Comment: the same code i have used it does not remove the icon from the window when i run the project just using the exe....where m not using the visual studio to run the project

Comment: @LnDCobra: Good answer, +1. Note that you could easily implement this as an attached property, which would enable removing the icon declaratively, in XAML

Comment: itz getting removed


my problem is its attaching all together new icon for exe file

Comment: this helped me alot...n i just wanted to share some info about wpf window icons...
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.icon.aspx

Comment: I have found that this soulution does not work if Aero is disabled in Windows 7 or if the application is run on Windows XP (and Windows 2003 I would guess).

Comment: @jmatthias Yes. The fix is to add this line at the bottom:

SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SETICON, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);

Comment: You may wish to add `SWP_NOACTIVATE(0x0010)` flag to prevent the window from being activated with `SetWindowPos` function.

Comment: I would use `EnsureWindowHandle()` instead of getting Handle.

Answer (score 24):

Just add this `WindowStyle="ToolWindow"` to your window properties.

Comment: not bad. But this hides maximize/minimize buttons too

Comment: Wow, I never knew it was this easy! But what will it look in the taskbar?

Comment: This work, but makes the Close X of the Window red!

Answer (score 12):

Here a simple and pure XAML solution:

```
<Window x:Class="...">

    <Window.Icon>
        <DrawingImage />
    </Window.Icon>

    ...

</Window>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The title is of course pushed by the empty icon but that is a small price to pay. I just hate messing with windows DLL just to remove an icon!

Comment: This appears to make the taskbar icon blank

Answer (score 7):

I just use very small transparent image as an icon (1x1 px) for WPF window.

Answer (score 2):

Create a transparent 1 by 1 icon and replace it with a standard one

```cs
Icon = BitmapSource.Create(1, 1, 0, 0, PixelFormats.Bgra32, null, new byte[4], 4);
```

Comment: Could you please extend your answer?