# How to remove the icon from title bar in Windows Presentation Framework(.Net)?

Tags: wpf

How to remove the icon from title bar in Windows Presentation Framework(.Net)?

I need just to remove the icon from the title bar only, not from any other place. 
When i switch my application from fullscreen to normal screen then the title bar icon is again appearing
Can anyone suggest any durable solution?

Comment: this link will help you https://www.wpftutorial.net/RemoveIcon.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing Icon from a WPF window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2341230/removing-icon-from-a-wpf-window)

Comment: These solutions are not durable. I have checked with my application.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
 {

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hwnd, int index);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hwnd, int index, int newStyle);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr hwndInsertAfter, int x, int y, int width, int height, uint flags);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, uint msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    const int GWL_EXSTYLE = -20;
    const int WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAME = 0x0001;
    const int SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
    const int SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;
    const int SWP_NOZORDER = 0x0004;
    const int SWP_FRAMECHANGED = 0x0020;
    const uint WM_SETICON = 0x0080;

    protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSourceInitialized(e);
        IntPtr hwnd = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;
        int extendedStyle = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);
        SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, extendedStyle | WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAME);
        SetWindowPos(hwnd, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_FRAMECHANGED);

    }
}
```

Comment: This is not working, when i switch my application from fullscreen to normal screen then the title bar icon is appearing again.

Comment: This is working perfectly for me, can you share your code?

Comment: and one more thing in the task bar where the application icon is present when you hover it the icon is still coming.

Comment: I don't think there are any tools that we can remove the icon from the taskbar. We can do only one thing, that is to use an empty icon. You can refer [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/313586/Removing-titlebar-and-taskbar-icons)

Comment: I want to remove from the icon from title bar not the taskbar