# Remove a window's title context menu, but leaving everything else intact

Tags: wpf, windows, window

The only way I found to remove the title context menu of a window is this:

```
SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE) & ~WS_SYSMENU);
```

Where WS_SYSMENU is something like 0x80000.

But this also hides the window's close button, which I don't want.

There is a workaround which I've not yet tried. I can probably override right click on the window, and also override the ALT+Space (or ALT+Up) key combinations. I'm using WPF.

More specifically I want a window, that looks like this:

1. Has no icon in the title bar
2. Has no context menu
3. Has no maximize button (not just disabled)
4. Has a minimize button

The first I can achieve with this https://stackoverflow.com/a/4553510/5539917

The third and forth point cannot be done at the same time. So instead I chose to hide the minimize and the maximize button, and use the close button and tray icon solution. (Clicking the close button won't close the app, but minimize it to tray icon.)

The only remaining is the second point. Is there an easy solution for that? I don't want to create a completely custom window, and I don't particularly like the workaround I mentioned.

Comment: You could draw a custom close button. That would be easier than a whole custom window.

Comment: `ShowInTaskBar` you can set that to false. Other than that you would have to draw your own window with desired behaviour.

Comment: @XAMlMAX ShowInTaskBar is already false

Comment: @montonero That's a good idea, I will look into it

Comment: I wouldn't know, as you didn't provide any XAML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want to do this as it can disable some windows customizations programs from letting users pin the window on top.  Please don't disable the title bar context.