# Why only top border is visible when ToolWindow is used?

Tags: wpf, border, mainwindow

I created new .NET WPF desktop application using Visual Studio 2019. The default mainwindow looks like this:

[image]

What I want is to hide the icon, which I accomplished by setting next property to Window

```
WindowStyle="ToolWindow"
```

It works, but now only Window's top black border is visible. No left, right or bottom are visible as in upper example (with Icon).

[image]

How can I add all window borders (visually the same as first example) and keep WindowStyle 'ToolWindow'? I tried adding BorderBrush and BorderThichness, but it's not the same. The result is here:

[image]

Comment: So u need to maintain `WindowStyle` and remove icon right?

Comment: @AvinashReddy yes exactly. In other words use normal window (minimize, resize and close buttons in the upper right corner don't make a difference for me) as long as icon is hidden.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing Icon from a WPF window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2341230/removing-icon-from-a-wpf-window)

Comment: Chek these links https://www.wpftutorial.net/RemoveIcon.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2341230/removing-icon-from-a-wpf-window/2341385

Comment: Well I looked before those links, but don't feel comfortable to mess with user32.dll.